# Como resgatar texto html do banco de dados?

Tags: html, banco-de-dados, front-end, tinymce

Estou usando o editor `TinyMCE`, os dados são salvos corretamente no banco de dados, porém não sei como faço para resgatá-los e mostrá-los na tela. Está me retornando assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia resolver? Agradeço a comunidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou utilizando laravel, a minha solução foi colocar o `{!! !!}` na view.

Comment: Isso é a  resposta da pergunta ou um comentário? Se for um comentário, não deve ser feito neste campo, e sim, numa edição na pergunta.

Comment: É a solução para a minha pergunta, então creio que seja a resposta

Comment: Ah sim, não estava muito claro, agora com a edição, ficou melhor :)

Comment: Felipe o facto de estar a utulizar Laravel devia ter sido colocado também na questão. Ainda bem que resolveu

Answer (score 0):

Gravar no banco: `$texto = addslashes($_POST['texto');`

Ler do banco: `$texto = stripslashes($linha['texto']); echo $texto;`